# Connecting faucet to splitter to mini-dishwasher

Tags: plumbing, faucet, dishwasher

Sorry for the crude drawing:

[image: Faucet connections]

At the top, you can see the faucet cap (female). Just below, the faucet splitter (both splits are male). On the right, the dishwasher input (female). I believe the threading is different for this last one, but I am unsure. I can measure if needed.

I am attempting to connect my faucet to a faucet splitter, and then to a dishwasher's water input tube.

The dimensions for the threads are shown in the picture, however, I do not know enough to figure out the thread's name (I am only familiar with the e.g. M5 notation for screws).

**Could anyone provide me with info on how to find the parts I need to connect everything up?** (*I am also willing to buy a **different faucet splitter** if it is cheaper / less messy*)

*Last note: I live in Europe, so threading might differ from NA*

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to bring that faucet part to plumbing store and try out. Here in the US the water hose connectors are typical 3/4 inch

Comment: it looks like the threads and genders are all reversed from what you need. The DW hose fits what you mark as the input, right? And the faucet's original aerator screws onto what you have labeled as the output, right? If so, you can just take the splitter back because it has all the right sizes to match up the parts in-store with the right polarity that you need (smaller female input, larger male output).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a female thread fitting.  Based on what I can find on metric faucets, yours should be a regular/standard size, with M22 female threads.  So you need either:

1. A double female M22 adapter—assuming your valve is also M22—similar to this (except I can't find one in an actual M22 size):

[image]

2. A [female diverter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/KES-Diverter-Polished-Replacement-Bathroom/dp/B09VBC6BD8), like this:
   [image]

Personally, I'd just go with the latter; it's not very expensive and will look much better.

Comment: Any reasonable plumbing supply store should be able to help out with either adapters or replacement diverters that will have the necessary threads and genders all 'round.

Comment: Sure, but "Europe" encompasses a vast area, not all of which may have easy access to a "reasonable plumbing supply store."

Comment: Quite true. It does, however, give the OP a pointer on where to head, if one is available. Often "big-box home improvement" stores aren't well stocked enough. Sometimes "local hardware store with terrifyingly over crowded shelves" will be just the right spot, too.